# javascript for loop to decrease

Tags: javascript, for-loop, operators

I have this jQuery for loop

```
for (; year <= endYear; year++) {
    html += '<option value="' + year + '"' + 
        (year == drawYear ? ' selected="selected"' : '') +
        '>' + year + '</option>';
}
```

year = 1950 and endYear = 2006.

My option values appear like so

```
1950
1951
1952
and so on
```

I am trying to get it to reverse

```
2006
2005
2004
and so on
```

How would I reverse this statement `for (; year <= endYear; year++) {`

Comment: `for (year=endYear; year >= 1950 ; year--) {` ?

Answer (score 8):

Reverse your for loop so it goes in the opposite direction!

```
var startYear = 1950;
var endYear = 2006;

for (var year = endYear; year >= startYear; year--) {
     html += '<option value="' + year + '"' + (year == drawYear ? ' selected="selected"' : "") + ">" + year + "</option>"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var year = endYear; year >= startYear; year=year-1) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue

```
for (year=endYear; year >= 1950 ; year--) {
```

Thanks dystroy